# URL Friendly using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Having the below urls, but only the first one works with my htaccess code. Please help to fix this for both url at time. Thank you.

URL 1: http://domain.com/index.php?id=Apple

Output : http://domain.com/Apple (This is ok)

URL 2: http://domain.com/index.php?id=Apple-Board&jid=Chief-Accountant

Output : http://domain.com/Apple-Board (This is not ok)

Expected Output : http://domain.com/Apple-Board/Chief-Accountant

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [B,L]
RewriteRule /id/(.*)/jobid/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1&jid=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&jid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&jid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, Thank you for your quick response. But Still it is not working. (URL 2: http://domain.com/index.php?id=Apple-Board&jid=Chief-Accountant

Output : http://domain.com/Apple-Board (This is not ok)

Expected Output : http://domain.com/Apple-Board/Chief-Accountant)

Comment: Thaks a lot anubhava. I am near to the output, need to work on php code for some fix. Thanks again.